# Add the URL path to html script src and render the page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take the URL path and add it to the `Script Src` value.
In my domain, if I go to the path `http://example.com:3001/form` I'll get the JSON format. So, I want to render that JSON format in my HTML page.
I have the JS and CSS code to work on that JSON but the main problem is the HTML page that should look the URL path data and use the URL path.
I only found the problem. How can I get that URL path and added it to the Script Src value?
The code is like this 
    `<script src="http://embed.js?src= "http://example.com:3001/`render the url path`"></script>`
Here the link `http://example.com:3001` will be fixed.

If the file is index.html in the example.com, I want this HTML to look for the path whenever I go to the `http://example.com` if no path then it should 404 error, or even blank is enough, but when I go to the `http://example.com/form` I will get the json so it should get the path after the `/ path` and added it to the script src then the link would be `http://example.com:3001/path`.

I have tried the JS of the window.location and few, but since I'm new and I'm running out of options.

Kindly let me know how to solve this issue

Comment: Lot of confusion...lets classified with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the full url by using `window.location.href` and add it to your src field.

If you want to just get the pathname of the url then you can use `window.location.pathname` and the add it to you URL in src of the script tag. So the final code will look like this

```
<script src="http://embed.js?src=http://example.com:3001/"+window.location.pathname></script>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry but its not working , im ending up with / at last. if i write the url `http://example.com/ct` it going to `http://example.com/`     , can you suggest me how can i send at that `ct` value and append to the code inside the script tag http://example.com:3001/

Comment: Should i want to add any `?` before the `ct` value to the url

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly are you trying to do. If you can share your code more and explain a bit more then it might help.

Comment: Okay , ill got step by step:
I have a domain which gives  a JSON reponse when ever i go to the `http://mykampaign.com:3001/wizard` use can see this link.
Now i have a HTML page in my localhost called index.html , and when i open / run the index.html with the with the src value  , it should fetch the src value and append it to the  `http://mykampaign.com:3001/value` and take the 
 JSON format , i have the JS and CSS files to render that JSON values but the problem is the src value is static , I'm trying to create dynamic html ,just based on the src value it will take the JSON response&use it

Comment: Even i have another code 
     `<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        Formio.createForm(document.getElementById('form'), 'https://examples.io/example');
      };
    </script>`  so here  the https link is fixed , so i want that to be dynamic. i want  to pass that `/example` in the URL rather than hard code inside in the html file.

Comment: From where would the dynamic value come?